# Term for useful unreproducible keyboard shortcut

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a expression that describes the situation where you accidentally hit some combination of keys in a software application, and you discover that it triggers some useful keyboard shortcut that you didn't know about, but you don't know what the exact key combination was, and you aren't able to reproduce it?

Comment: A [fluke](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fluke)

Comment: You could try reading the Help files. :)

Comment: How about "magic shortcut"? Or "mystery shortcut"?

Comment: I guess I should ask for the word for the opposite: the cat steps on the keyboard and the computer shuts down!  I don't know what she hit, but I hope she doesn't do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose **Heisenstroke**! From the lineage of the [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). You heard it here first.

Answer (score 2):

As to the first part, *serendipitous*.

> ser·en·dip·i·ty  (noun)
>   1. an aptitude for making desirable discoveries by accident.
>   2. good fortune; luck.

As for not being able to reproduce it, that's a little tougher.  Maybe this:

> dis·com·fi·ture (noun)
>   1. disconcertion; confusion; embarrassment.
>   2. frustration of hopes or plans.

Comment: +1 because in trying to minus one I discovered that it fits the feel of the situation quite well.

Answer (score 2):

We used to call them "happy accidents" and when users called the help desk wondering how to undo/redo what they did, we told them to RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***tip of one's fingers***, as in "Oh drat, what was that keystroke? I swear, it's on the tip of my fingers!"

Comment: That implies (to me) that the person who did it *once* knew and then forgot.